# django channels Connection Errors only when tried with User_login

Tags: python, django, redis, django-channels

Running channels with daphne.

```
django version: 2.0.4

asgiref==2.2.0

asgi-redis==1.4.3

channels==2.1.5

channels-redis==2.3.1
```

I'm trying to connect websoket. When I tried to connect with Anonymous user(without user login), it works well. But, when there is user, it doesn't work well.

The one point that I get by using `pdb.set_trace()` is that there is `self.scope['cookies']['sessionid']` when I tried with user login. But there is no result in `self.scope['cookies']['sessionid']` when there is no user(Anonymous user)

I thought that it might be related to `AuthMiddlewareStack` and I looked into the source code. But, I cannot find the source of the problem.

Can you help me?
Below are my codes.

1. settings.py

   ```
   ASGI_APPLICATION = 'businessproject.routing.application'
   ```

   CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
       'default': {
           'BACKEND': 'channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer',
           'CONFIG': {
               "hosts": [('127.0.0.1', 6379)],
           },
       },
   }
2. models.py

```
class MyUser(AbstractUser):
    galaxy_num=models.IntegerField(default=1)
    onoff=models.IntegerField(default=1, null=True)
```

```
def __str__(self):
    return self.username
```

3. consumers.py

```
from channels.generic.websocket import WebsocketConsumer, AsyncWebsocketConsumer
import json, pdb
from asgiref.sync import async_to_sync
```

class TestConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):

```
async def connect(self):
    # Join room group
    self.group_name="likes"

    await self.channel_layer.group_add(
        self.group_name,
        self.channel_name
    )

    await self.accept()

async def disconnect(self, close_code):

    await self.channel_layer.group_discard(
        self.group_name,
        self.channel_name
    )

async  def receive(self, text_data):
    text_data_json = json.loads(text_data)
    message = text_data_json['message']

    await self.channel_layer.group_send(
        self.group_name,
        {
            'type': 'like_message',
            'message': message
        }
    )

# Receive message from room group
async def like_message(self, event):
    message = "%s님이 게시물을 좋아합니다."%event['message']

    # Send message to WebSocket
    await self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
        'message': message
    }))
```

4. routing.py

```
from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
from cebula import routing


application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    # (http->django views is added by default)
    'websocket': AuthMiddlewareStack(
        URLRouter(
            routing.websocket_urlpatterns
        )
    ),
})
```

this is the console result

WebSocket connection to `ws://127.0.0.1:8000/ws/test/`

failed: **Error during WebSocket handshake: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET**

If you need more information, please tell me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem myself.
I don't know reason exactly,
but if you eliminate `AuthMiddlewareStack` in routing.py
everything works well.
If someone know the reason, please tell me.

Comment: Removing `AuthMiddlewareStack` solves the issue, because you're now telling Django Channels to skip user authentication. Which is ok if you don't care about users being authenticated to open and access your websockets. If you want authentication you have to define a `CustomAuthMiddlewareStack` and put it in your routing.py. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue. Not sure what you are using for authentication, but we are using `JWT` and our own `AuthUser` model. So we had to build our own `JWTAuthMiddleware` specific for our project. Below is our example:

**routing.py**

```
from .middleware import JWTAuthMiddleware

application = ProtocolTypeRouter(
    {
    "websocket": JWTAuthMiddleware(
            (URLRouter(myapp.routing.websocket_urlpatterns))
        )
    }
)
```

**middleware.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth.models import AnonymousUser
from django.db import close_old_connections
from rest_framework_jwt.authentication import BaseJSONWebTokenAuthentication


class JsonTokenAuthMiddleware(BaseJSONWebTokenAuthentication):
    """
    Token authorization middleware for Django Channels 2
    """

    def __init__(self, inner):
        self.inner = inner

    def __call__(self, scope):

        try:
        # Close old database connections to prevent usage of timed out 
        connections
            close_old_connections()
            User = get_user_model()
            user_id = scope["query_string"].decode("utf-8")
            user = User.objects.get(uuid=user_id)
            if user.is_authenticated:
                scope["user"] = user
        except:
            scope["user"] = AnonymousUser()

        return self.inner(scope)
```

Here are the docs: [Channels Authentication](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/authentication.html)

Hope this helps someone somewhere!